# Эмуляция нагрузки на сервер

Tags: php

Всем привет.
Клиент требует, чтобы у него в админке отображалась "нагрузка на сервер в процентах".

На что нагрузка, сами понять не можем, понятие весьма абстрактное. Но как ее надо как то эмулировать с помощью php?

Пока пришла идея только брать общее количество свободного места и посчитать процент свободного от него.
p.s. OS Debian 7

Comment: Нагрузка на что? На диск, на оперативку, на проц? Есть [loadavg](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sys-getloadavg.php) для линукса, но это даже не проценты.

Comment: Сами не знаем на что. На что угодно. Клиент пришел, сказал хочу видеть нагрузку в процентах. ОС там стоит debian 7

Comment: Может, стоит пойти другим путем и сказать клиенту, что нагрузка не рассчитывается втупую? В крайнем случае выводить ему loadaverage поделенный на количество ядер.

Comment: Там клиент из 90-х, ему до фонаря наши объяснения.

Comment: Берите вышеприведенный load average и делите на количество ядер. Количество ядер читайте из `/proc/cpuinfo`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Непонятно почему вы включили в название слово "эмуляция". Вот стандартная функция для load average: http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sys-getloadavg.php

Там же в примерах демонстрируют как получить аналогичные цифры читая /proc/loadavg напрямую. А также для Windows — через вызов uptime.

Comment: Да, спасибо. Я уже разобрался. То что нужно.

Answer (score 3):

```
$output = shell_exec('cat /proc/loadavg');
$loadavg = substr($output,0,strpos($output," "));
```